# Hive - Using date_add in a where clause

Tags: performance, hive, hiveql

I have a table that is partitioned by date. To query the last 10 days of data I usually write something that looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = date_add(current_date, -10);
```

A coworker said this makes the query less efficient that using a simple date string. Is this the case? Can some explain this to me? Is there a way to write a dynamic date into the where clause that is efficient?

Answer (score 1):

The only problem here can be with partition pruning. Partition pruning may not work with function in some Hive versions. You can easily check it yourself by executing `EXPLAIN EXTENDED <your select query>` command. It will print all partition paths to be queried.

In this case, use pre-calculated in a shell value  and pass it as a parameter:

```
date_var=$(date +'%Y_%m_%d' --date "-10 day")

#call your script
hive -hivevar date_var="$date_var" -f your_script.hql
```

And use variable in the script:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = '${hivevar:date_var}';
```

And if partition pruning works good, you do not need to bother at all.